# Is bitmap can be used after it's been garbage collected?

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, imageview, bitmapfactory

I was watching this video, that talks about memory allocation for bitmaps and garbage collection:

[DevBytes: Bitmap Allocation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8)

Chet is talking about how it was managed by the developer prior to `SDK 11` by using `.recycle()` and after `SDK 11` it's is managed by the `GC`.

To a more practical case currently I'm writing an application that in one of the `Activities` I create **many fragments** which basically hold a **scroll-able layout of** `ImageViews`. those Images are created from the device camera. So I encountered the `OutOfMemory` problem and realized that I had to re-size the Images I got from the camera because the result was really high res and took all my application memory.

So now I'm re-sizing and setting the images with very small sizes using this method:

`img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 100, 70));`

when `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile` is:

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{ // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
  }
```

}

but still I never call `.recycle()` method on any of the bitmaps because I need them all to be present on screen.

**My Questions Are:**

**1.** if I call  `.recycle()` on a bitmap that was already set to an `ImageView` using `setImageBitmap` does it mean that it will disappear from the screen or maybe I will receive an exception?

**2.** If I don't call `.recycle()` but I'm running my application on Galaxy S3`(4.2.1)` for example while my application is `minSDK is 8`. Will the GC kick to do the job for me?

**3.** In the video he is talking about bitmap reuse using the `BitmapFactory` object, is there a way to do that prior to SDK 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Recycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29)

1. I have never used it in this fashion. According to the documentation you're risking an exception
2. Yes. If you have set all references to your bitmap to null, it will be collected.

   > This operation cannot be reversed, so it should only be called if you
   >   are sure there are no further uses for the bitmap. This is an advanced
   >   call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process
   >   will free up this memory when there are no more references to this
   >   bitmap.
3. Don't know about bitmap "reuse" in this fashion. Look at the "[Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)" and "[Caching Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)" topics for further information.

Comment: just complementing your very good answer: 1. Yes, it will crash, I've done it before. 3. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap that BitmapFactoryOption is only available on API level 11, so no, there's no way to do it prior to 11. Also it only work if the bitmap have the same size (which should work for camera).

Comment: So basically while my ImageViews are on screen I have to hold all those source Bitmaps in my memory, correct?

Comment: So I'm in a problem now, I'm constantly adding images to this screen, and even if they are small eventually the outOfMemory will appear, how can avoid it then?

Comment: Well, I think you could do worse than to look at the sample application here https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip